# netstat shows an ESTABLISHED connection with no process

Tags: networking, netstat

I am debugging some problems with postfix. When I establish a connection nothing happens and `netstat` shows:

```
$ netstat -anp
...
tcp        0      0 129.132.202.106:25          129.132.179.232:60154       ESTABLISHED -
```

Why is the process missing?

`lsof` does not show the established connection

```
$ lsof -n -i :25
COMMAND   PID    USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
master   6139    root   11u  IPv4 472858      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:smtp (LISTEN)
master  20033    root   11u  IPv4 523921      0t0  TCP 129.132.202.106:smtp (LISTEN)
smtpd   20042 postfix    6u  IPv4 523921      0t0  TCP 129.132.202.106:smtp (LISTEN)
```

Traffic:

```
11:26:44.182443 IP 129.132.179.232.59517 > 129.132.202.106.25: S 3522488764:3522488764(0) win 65535 <mss 1460,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,timestamp 73851028 0,sackOK,eol>
11:26:44.182831 IP 129.132.202.106.25 > 129.132.179.232.59517: S 3950923498:3950923498(0) ack 3522488765 win 5792 <mss 1460,sackOK,timestamp 18832449 73851028,nop,wscale 7>
11:26:44.183150 IP 129.132.179.232.59517 > 129.132.202.106.25: . ack 1 win 4117 <nop,nop,timestamp 73851029 18832449>
```

and then nothing more

How do I find out why the listening process is not there? If I attach `strace` to `master` nothing is shown. No activity whatsoever during the attempted connection.

Comment: What exactly is missing in the `netstat` output?

Comment: The PID and process. Something like `ESTABLISHED 12775/nscd`

Comment: These lines just end in `ESTABLISHED` with my `netstat` - where did you see that? Which options?

Comment: It's `netstat -p` what you're looking for?!

Comment: You need to show the `netstat` command you are running, not just the output.

Comment: I am using netstat -p and the process is shown (is the `-` at the end of the row)

Answer (score 5):

You need to run `netstat` using `sudo`.

Without root privileges, `netstat` is unable to go poking around in the processes of other users (denoted by a `-` in the last column of your output), so the `-p` option will only identify processes owned by you, and this process is apparently not owned by you.

So the solution simply becomes:

```
sudo netstat -apn
```

Comment: Even when run as root and with `-t` the process is not shown (just `-`)